# compile TOR for IOS using linux

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, tor

I'm using an old version of tor (MobileTor) which has been compiled about 3 year's ago to be run on jailbroken apple ios devices. unfortunately this project has not been updated for a long time.
Is there anyway to cross compile the TOR source-code using a Linux machine for apple IOS? and would it be enough just to compile the source code or should I do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux may be what you are looking for.